# BasicMediaPlayerPluginMac an example project by firebreath

Tags: macos, firebreath

I have followed the following steps:
ran prepmac.sh examples
tried to build the FireBreath.xcodeproj got a lot many errors then added two header files  and SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h to the BasicMediaPlayerPluginMac.mm only then i was able to build the project on success i linked it to Library/InternetPlugins folder. On opening the html page for the media player it says plugin missing. Application of x-vnd.fbBasicMediaPlayer not found, cannot read the plugin as error. I tried adding two other frameworks namely coregraphics/coregraphics.h and cocoa/cocoa.h but the build was unsuccesfull. I'm trying to look into the plugin and how it is developed.

Comment: Note that the BasicMediaPlayer is at this point not at all a basic media player on mac; it's a drawing example, and it hasn't been updated in quite awhile.

Answer (score 1):

Start from simplest possible setup. Build FBTestPlugin, it should not require any changes to the setup. Put the plugin to /Library/Internet-Plug Ins  and restart your browser before trying to load it by the html sample supplied.

Note that project files should be never modified explicitly, only through cmake files and prep-scripts.

Good luck, these plugins are not simple to develop :)